# Batch input - Send textarea content to a hidden field before the final submit

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, curl

I posted this for help and it may be useful for somebody else. I'm not clear on how to do this, or if it's even possible. The post content is from the textarea and I want to recreate the content into a hidden fields to post to another page. At first thought it could be done with Ajax, but not sure.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$total = $_POST["textarea"];    
if($total != "") 
    {                       
        $pieces = explode("\n",$total);         
        $i=0;
        foreach($pieces as $piece)
        {               

        $pieces2 = $piece;  
        $piece3 = array_map('trim', explode(" ", $pieces2));

        // gets the 1st offset in the array
            if(strpos($piece3[0], 'http') !== FALSE)
            {       
                $output .= '<input type="hidden" name="url['.$i.']" value="'.$piece3[0].'" />'."\r\n";
            }

// no links in the textarea box then error message                  
    }else{
        $output .= "NO READABLE IMPORT<br>";
    }

}
```

as for the html. this form send to another page with a step 2. it's like this.

```
    <form name="batch_import" action="addurls.php?step=2" method="post">            
            <textarea id="textarea" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
            <?php echo $output; ?>  
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Import" class="inputbutton" />

        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do this server-side? So page1 posts to page2, then posts to page 3 via AJAX? Is this what you are looking to do? You can definitely add a hidden field to the DOM and copy the textarea data to it, and send it to another page via AJAX, but why not just:

1) Create a hidden field on Page1
2) Use jQuery or JavaScript to copy the data to the hidden field
3) Submit via AJAX to page 3 before submitting the form to page 2.

Is this it, or am I missing something? Maybe let me know what you are trying to accomplish and I can better answer.

Comment: My idea is similar about using jquery to get the textarea content. then loop the content to create a query string with PHP before submitting the post strings to the other page. Then, I should get the document.getElementById() instead of submitting the form with textarea. For this reason, I removed the name attribute from the textarea, that way it's not submitting meaningless data.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total = $_POST["textarea"]; 
//.....
<textarea id="textarea" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
```

To  make the POST-data available to PHP, the textarea needs to have the **name**-attribute "textarea" (the id-attribute is meaningless when sending a form, only form-fields with a name-attribute will be sended)

Comment: Thank for help. i don't want to send the textarea at all. i want to populate the hidden fields with each line in the textarea. so there might be many hidden fields from the array.

Comment: And the array comes from `$_POST["textarea"]`, where should this come from if not from the sended textarea?